# Help with identifying a connector

Tags: connector, identification

Can you please help me to identify this connector?

It's being used to connect a 6V power supply (4 x D batteries) to a PCB

[image: unknown connector 1]

[image: unknown connector 2]

**EDIT:**

The pitch appears to be just over 2.5mm. Please see image below for evidence of this. I've also attached a further image of the top elevation.

[image: connector pitch]

[image: top elevation]

Comment: Not sure, but looks suspiciously like [a 2-pin JST connector](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9914) perhaps?

Comment: I ruled that out because the guides at the top and bottom are different...

Comment: Can you give some measurements? Is it a common 2.54mm from pin to pin or something else?

Comment: @Arsenal I've just updated the question. I believe it is 2.54mm pitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"JST" is actually the name of a company that manufactures many types of connectors, and is not actually a connector type. What you have there is similar to a [J.S.T. XH series](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=277) connector.

Comment: That looks to be it! In particular a XHP-2. Thank you very much!